# Assistance with z index causing various errors

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, z-index

Please have a look at this webpage - http://dev.topyaps.com/how-awesome-are-you

This post is built by a wordpress plugin that I developed. I am facing various issues because of the z index property of elements. The issues are -

1) On scroll the menu merges with the floating bar on the page. 
CSS of menu -

```
kodda_container {
z-index: 999 !important;
width: 1220px;
height: 40px !important;
background-color: ;
border-top: solid transparent;
border-right: solid transparent;
border-bottom: solid transparent;
border-left: solid transparent;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, transparent);
}
```

Css of floating bar -

```
.scoreBox {
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 997;
}
```

2) On clicking the submit button a center box appears. The center box has to be on the top while it hides.

Css of center box -

```
element.style {
    padding: 6px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: -206px;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
}
```

3) Try clicking on login and register button on the homepage - http://dev.topyaps.com/. This is the actual styling of the login/register popup. But in the post "How awesome are you?" , when we click on login/register the styling changes to the styling of the center box (the one that appears on clicking the Submit button).

Css of login box -

```
element.style {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -163.5px;
    margin-left: -230px;
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

Please try to tell me the way by which I can fix these issues.

Comment: Can you show some code and HTML?

Comment: I think most of the code can be seen using the "Inspect Element" option on the browser. Still if you think you need some specific code let me know.

Comment: We do not need to take our time and go looking for your code, it would be nice in the future to make it easier for us to help you and post the code yourself or provide a jsFiddle with only the section that you need assistance for.

Comment: @Alin well I think my query will need max 15 minutes of time .. and when browsers have this option to make things easier for developers then why not utilize it .. once you go on the link I gave you will understand the issues on your own .. I am not asking for hours of work, just need a basic understanding of what the issue is

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Dean.DePue .. Please check the code now

Comment: It's not about z-index, but about the nesting of your div's. A free floating div (modal blocker) can't have a z-index putting it "in between" some nested divs afaik.

Comment: @AxelAmthor can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Your problem is not the z-index but your scripts are in conflict, you probably have multiple div id's that match by name but not by style, therefore you get a conflict of style and priority. Id's must be unique in a website.

Comment: suppose you have an outer visible div "A" with z-index of 1 and within that another div "B" with z-index 4. Aside of the first div and outside of all others, you have another div "L". Giving the last one the z-index of "3" will NOT put this as a layer in between "A" and "B" but either on top of both or below all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage is being styled by:

`http://dev.topyaps.com/wp-content/plugins/simplemodal-login/css/default.css?ver=1.0.7`

Whereas your content page is being styled by:

`http://dev.topyaps.com/wp-content/plugins/challenges/modal/jquery.modal.css?ver=3.9.1`

Looks like you may have two, conflicting plugins at work.